# Second cohomology of a torsion-free hyperbolic group

Tags: group-theory, riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Does any body know examples of torsion-free hyperbolic group $G$ such that $H^2(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ (trivial G-action on $\mathbb{R}$)?

In fact I am interested in if there are known examples of *even-dimensional, closed* Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ with negative sectional curvature such that $b_2(M)=0$.

I noticed [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040938396000468/pdf?md5=81bba9f141993ee7f885ea6b997667d1&pid=1-s2.0-S0040938396000468-main.pdf) by Epstein-Fujiwara, but I am not sure if the result for bounded group cohomology gives information on my question.

Comment: There are many examples of hyperbolic 3-manifolds which are even integer homology spheres.

Comment: Oh, I forgot, I want even-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Such a product will not be hyperbolic.

Comment: @user188722: Then you should update the question.

Comment: Huh, wow, I was being silly. Apparently in fact a compact hyperbolic manifold is never a nontrivial product of two other manifolds: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324273/can-a-hyperbolic-manifold-be-a-product

Comment: Your best bet would be compact quaternionic-hyperbolic manifolds.

Comment: My suggestion is to write directly to Nicolas Bergeron (he is at ENS, Paris) and ask him what is known about $b_2(\Gamma)$ for torsion-free uniform quaternionic-hyperbolic lattices (quaternionic dimension $>1$). My guess is that it is either known to be always positive or always zero. If it is known to be zero, you get your examples. If it is known to be positive, then your question (about manifolds of negative curvature) is almost surely an open problem.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my comments:

First of all, the question about hyperbolic groups is very different from the one about fundamental groups of closed connected manifolds of negative curvature: "Most" hyperbolic groups are very much unlike "manifold groups." Second: The mentioned paper by Epstein and Fujiwara is interesting but totally irrelevant for the purpose of your question. Now, your real question is:

> Is there an example of a closed connected even-dimensional manifold $M$ of negative curvature  such that $b_2(M)=0$?

Here is what I know: The first interesting case, of course, is of 4-dimensional manifolds. Such a manifold $M$ would have positive Euler characteristic (see the references [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_conjecture#Positively_or_negatively_curved_Riemannian_manifolds)), hence, effectively, you are asking about the existence of a negatively curved 4-dimensional rational homology sphere. This is an open problem (stated explicitly for manifolds of constant negative curvature by Bruno Martelli, I think). If there is such a hyperbolic 4-manifold, it would have the smallest possible volume among hyperbolic 4-manifolds.

Among locally-symmetric manifolds of negative curvature, complex-hyperbolic ones always have $b_2>0$ (because of the Kahler class). I do not believe there are any explicitly known examples (say, meaning that somebody computed their Betti numbers) of closed real-hyperbolic manifolds of dimension $\ge 6$. There are also no known vanishing theorems for $b_2$ in the class of manifolds. (All the known results are on the "nonvanishing side", they are of the type: There exists a finite-sheeted covering space with positive Betti numbers $b_i$ so some values of $i$.) This leaves one with quotients of quaternionic-hyperbolic spaces (and of the Cayley-hyperbolic plane). While there are no explicitly known examples (again, meaning that somebody computed Betti numbers), there might be vanishing/nonvanishing theorems for $b_2$ known in this class.

As for negatively curved manifolds  of dimension $\ge 4$ which are not locally-symmetric, there is only a handful of constructions (which *mostly* use locally-symmetric manifolds as their starting point) and no known construction can ensure vanishing of $b_2$.

Thus, unless there are known vanishing results for $b_2$ in the case of torsion-free cocompact discrete subgroups of isometries of quaternionic-hyperbolic spaces ${\mathbf H}{\mathbb H}^n, n\ge 2$, your question  should be treated as an open problem.